# Setting border-top-width: 0px; on Input changes whole border appearance

Tags: html, css

I want to display two input fields under each other with no margin, no padding and no double border (so it pretty much looks like a regular table, with a single separation 
line between each field).

Removing the margin was easy (`margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;`), but when I tried to remove the top border with  `border-top-width: 0px;`, the whole appearance of the input border changed to a lighter grey and the size looks larger too. This effect happens in all browsers.

Here is an example:
HTML

```
<div class="test">
    <input type="text" value="Test" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" value="Test" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
input {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.test input {
    border-top-width: 0px;
}
.test input:first-child {
    border-top-width: 2px;
}
```

Fiddler: http://fiddle.jshell.net/32een/1/

Image explaining what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.test input {
    border-top: 0;
}
.test input:first-child {
    border-top: 2px solid #ccc;
}
```

also, on your code, you can replace "0px" by "0", for optimization.

Comment: let me explain better: browsers normally have a "default" border for objects. When you want no border, you should set border:0. When you want to set another detail, browser will not render default border anymore (that's why they become larger and gray) - Then, you have to provide type of border, line and color so browser can handle the border way you want.

Comment: A trusted source to help with my previous comment - extracted from w3c: `Note: Always declare the border-style property before the border-top-width property. An element must have borders before you can change the width.` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-top_width.asp

Comment: Thanks, this solved my problem. Here is an update to the sample Fiddler: http://fiddle.jshell.net/tJQpv/
CSS: 

.test {
    margin: 5px;
}

input {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.test input {
    border: 1px inset #ccc;
    border-top-width: 0;
}
.test input:first-child {
    border-top: 1px inset #ccc;
}

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok with tables...

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red;"><input type="text" value="" style="border: 0; width: 100%;" /><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border:1px solid red;"><input type="text" value="" style="border: 0; width: 100%;" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the effect

[image: foo]

Answer (score 0):

Redefine browser border style:

```
input {
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    outline: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

**UPD:** and remove 'px' for zero values.

Answer (score 0):

That's what happens when you start to style input elements.

Browsers generally have two defaults for inputs. One modern looking with thin borders (and sometimes glow effects) that is used if you don't style them at all, and one ancient looking with heavy inset borders that is used as default when you touch the style.

So, if you want to style the borders, you have to specify a complete style including style, width and color, to get the look that you want.

Something like:

```
.test input {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top-width: 0;
}
.test input:first-child {
  border-top-width: 1px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using content editable divs. That way you can style the inputs however you want. I did the following in the your jsfiddle and it worked.

HTML:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="input" contenteditable="true">Test</div>
    <div class="input" contenteditable="true">Test</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 100px;
    margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

This gives the look that you wanted